# Is there any benefit to awaiting async versions of .NET functions vs. using the synchronous versions?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Many .NET classes provide a synchronous and asynchronous version of functions; for example, `System.IO.Stream` provides `CopyTo(Stream)` and `CopyToAsync(Stream)`.

I'm working on some code that *always* prefers to `await` the asynchronous version, instead of just invoking the synchronous version. This seems like it just creates extra work for (potentially) suspending the context and dispatching to another thread.

For example, `await stream.CopyToAsync(otherStream)` instead of `stream.CopyTo(otherStream)`.

Is there some benefit to using the `async` versions of these functions if they're immediately awaited on, instead of just invoking the synchronous versions directly?

Comment: It won't block the UI

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. Put some effort into your moderation.

Comment: @James: There is no UI in this case.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee looks like a dupe to me (one of many since this language feature is confusing and this particular question gets asked *a lot*). If you disagree, please edit your question to point out in wha exact way this is not a dupe.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: I'm specifically asking if there is a benefit to **immediately awaiting** an async function vs. using the synchronous version. I'm not asking a generic 'What is the benefit of async-await?'

Comment: Awaiting immediately is the 90% case for `await` use. The point is to avoid wasting *threads* - while your I/O request is processing (something that takes much more time than the context switch), you release the thread back to wherever it came from (e.g. the UI, or the thread pool).

Comment: @CollinDauphinee the dupe says the following: *"improves scalability by reducing memory/thread usage"* - by *not* blocking a thread you improve your system resources usage.